# Using realistic materials in a Game Engine

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, photorealism

I'm using Blender to create a game level for my Game.
**But the Problem is that My game Engine doesn't support PBR, also, it doesn't support import in Cycles mode.**
I'm using Godot Engine 2.1.4.
Fortunately, it supports Blender Render mode. I know its outdated renderer, and I can't create everything realistic there.
So, Is blender Render Capable of doing realistic projects.
Thanks For the help in Advance!! :)

Comment: I mean, with enough faking you can make it look pretty good. Between that and baking you should be able to make something work. Not sure what the question is . . .

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90740/cycles-materials-in-game-engines and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity

Comment: This old approach is probably what you are looking for: https://cgcookie.com/2015/05/20/pbr-in-blenders-viewport/