# How to Closely fake PBR in non-PBR using blender?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, photorealism

I'm using blender since few months. I've been seriously impressed with Blender. I want to achieve realism. But unfortunately, my game engine doesn't support PBR. It works on OpenGL 2, gltf. 

So, I'm unable to use cycles renderer in the blender for my game engine.
Can I get realism without PBR on Blender Internal?
Can I use cycles in my engine (baking or other methods?)
How to fake PBR in my game engine, Godot 2?
Are Diffuse, Displacement, Normal, Specular and AO enough for Realism?

**If I'm missing something, or some tricks, please do tell.**

any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not repeat the same question you had asked before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94607/using-realistic-materials-in-a-game-engine. If you are not getting answers add additional information to your original post.

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @cegaton here i'm trying to learn how to fake pbr....... sorry, let me edit a bit.