# How would I get cycles materials in the BGE?

Tags: materials, game-engine

I have a city model but when ever I go to the BGE it has materials. I have tried scripts and making the textures internal. Nothing has worked. I can't re-material everything because there are dozens of textures.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98201/63966

Comment: Also check https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90740/63966